# C# Universal App: add github repository as dependency

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

we are developing a SDK. We want developers being able to integrate this SDK into their projects. I know that in Visual Studio it is possible to create a new project as class library to later integrate the .dll file. 
But is there any other possibility than integrating the .dll or adding the classes manually? Something like a dependency on a Github repository maybe?

Thank you!

Comment: I like the question, but I've no idea how you could go about working with it. What if the users couldn't access the repository and the code depends on it? It essentially renders the project useless.

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly but sounds like you are looking for https://www.nuget.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have options:

- Make a [nuget](http://nuget.org/) for your SDK
- Open source your SDK on GitHub, write a readme, let developer pull your repo and add to their project manually
- (NOT RECOMMEND) make an [extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/) and let developer download it. Or provide a .dll file for them to add to their projects.

The reason I dont recommend making an extension is: It makes CI and testing a lots harder. You cant easily install dependency extension on CI environment.